# Cannot update form from Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload

I have a form with a lot of textboxes, dropdown menus and so on.
I use this form for entering NEW data but I also want to use the same page to CHANGE data. But then I have to fill the data with the information of the customer to be changed.

Now in Page_Load I have

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.PageTitle(PageTitles.UpdateAdd);

        NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
        if (nvc.Count == 2 && nvc["ThisIsAnUpdate"] == "1")
        {
            // Ladies and gentlemen, we have an update. Do the work.
            ThisIsAnUpdate.Value = "1";

            DetailedAddressEntity myCustomer = new RetreiveInformation().FetchDetailedInformation(nvc["ID"]);

            SetupEdit(myCustomer);
        }
    }
```

Then in SetupEdit I do this:

```
    protected void SetupEdit(DetailedAddressEntity dae)
    {
        FirstName.Text = dae.aFirstName;
        LastName.Text = dae.aLastName;
        SubscriberNumber.Text = dae.aSubscriberNumber;
        ... and so on...
    }
```

FirstName, LastName and SubscriberNumber never changes. They work perfectly when I use the page to create a new Customer since then I do postback to fill these textboxes, but when I try to access them when the page loads ... nothing.

I know the code in SetupEdit is actually run, but after the page is already drawn in my browser. I tried to force a postback, but that didn't work either.

Helps?

More explanation: Page_Load first set's the title of the page through the main page, since I do this without trouble I assumed I would be able to fill the textboxes too.
DetailedAddressEntity myCusomter is just a gazillion variables fetched from the DB.
I use the fetched information to fill the textboxes, but - alas - no info in them.

More info:
I moved the database call to SetupEdit and created a button on the page and called that function just to see if the function was broken. It works perfectly. It fetches all the info and fills up my textboxes perfectly.

But not if I call the same from Page_Load.

```
    protected void SetupEdit(string ID)
    {
        DetailedAddressEntity dae = new RetreiveInformation().FetchDetailedInformation(ID);

        FirstName.Text = dae.aFirstName;
        LastName.Text = dae.aLastName;
        SubscriberNumber.Text = dae.aSubscriberNumber;
        ... and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
        Master.PageTitle(PageTitles.UpdateAdd);

        NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
        if (nvc.Count == 2 && nvc["ThisIsAnUpdate"] == "1")
        {
            // Ladies and gentlemen, we have an update. Do the work.
            ThisIsAnUpdate.Value = "1";

            DetailedAddressEntity myCustomer = new RetreiveInformation().FetchDetailedInformation(nvc["ID"]);

            SetupEdit(myCustomer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nopes, that didn't work. I am beginning to start to wonder if I call the page wrongly. :/ But I get all the variables correctly and they are set when I step through them in the debugger. Still don't work though.